# How can I link labels in a SelectCheckBoxes component in Visualforce?

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

I have an `<apex:SelectCheckBoxes>` component in my Visualforce page, which gets its select options from an Apex method. I want to have a label with a link appearing next to each checkbox. How can I achieve this? Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to accomplish this is by using apex:inputCheckbox controls individually, rather than relying on selectCheckboxes to do all the rendering for you. It's hard to get more specific in a suggestion because the question can be answered in many ways.

If, for example, you need these checkboxes to appear in a list alongside SObject instances, create a wrapper class. If they are essentially a-la-carte, you can create a class that contains a Boolean and create a list of instances of this class. Then create a dataTable, pageBlockTable, etc., and in one of the columns you include the checkbox component. Or simply use apex:repeat if you don't want any of the other table formatting.

Here's the repeat example from the VF guide:

```
<!-- Page: -->
<apex:page controller="repeatCon" id="thePage">
   <apex:repeat value="{!strings}" var="string" id="theRepeat">
      <apex:outputText value="{!string}" id="theValue"/><br/>
   </apex:repeat>
</apex:page>

/*** Controller: ***/
public class repeatCon 
{
   public String[] getStrings() 
   {
      return new String[]{'ONE','TWO','THREE'};
   }
}
```

Replacing outputText with inputCheckbox and a String array with Boolean. Then simply start with an apex:outputLink and follow it with the checkbox.

- EDIT -

Here's an example of using a class to get the job you want done.

Apex:

```
public class Example 
{
   public List<CheckboxClass> theCheckboxes {get; private set;} // Reference THIS array

   public Example()
   {
      theCheckboxes = new List<CheckboxClass>();
      theCheckboxes.add(new Checkbox(true));
      theCheckboxes.add(new Checkbox(false));
      theCheckboxes.add(new Checkbox(true));
      theCheckboxes.add(new Checkbox(false));
   }

   public class CheckboxClass
   {
      public Boolean theCheckbox {get; private set;}

      public CheckboxClass(Boolean b)
      {
         this.theCheckbox = b;
      }
   }
}
```

Visualforce:

```
<apex:form>
   <apex:pageBlock>
      <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!theCheckboxes}" var="item">
         <apex:column headerValue="The Checkboxes">
            <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!item.theCheckbox}">
         </apex:column>
      </apex:pageBlockTable>
   </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
```

I haven't tested this, but this is the idea I believe you're looking for.

Comment: Yep, a wrapper is definitely the way forward for this one. An alternative might be to use jQuery to turn labels to links, or insert links, but a wrapper will be less effort IMO.

Comment: thanks for help.but If i use inputCheckBoxes I want to reference their value with an array in controller,not individual variables.how to do this

Comment: This is your array: public List<CheckboxClass> theCheckboxes {get; private set;} // Reference THIS array

Comment: hey thank you all for your replies.Finally I did it using javascript,as I wanted to use selectCheckBoxes to make the things easier